# Why setting background color for my header div also sets color for the rest of other divs?

Tags: css

I set color-background for .header and .footer to yellow. But it also sets same background colors for the content div, why ? It isn't logicial.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>
    <style type="text/css">

        .header {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        .footer {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        .column {
            width: 50%;
        }
        div.right {
            float: right;
        }
        div.left {
            float: left;    
        }

        img {
          float: right;
          margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class='header'>
    header
</div>

<div class='left column'>
    <img src="css-float.png">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.
</div>

<div class='right column'>
    <img src="css-float.png">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.
</div>

<div class='footer'>
    footer
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathiasaurus is spot on. You could clear your non floating elements, mainly the footer.

```
.header,
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
```

or add

```
.header,
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

to include them in the flow.

Comment: Thanks for solution, but I do want to understand the rationale behind that side effect of float which deals about positionning and should not deal with color.

Comment: When you float an element on the page - you're just forcing it's flow on the page, and obscuring it's block status - similar to display: inline-block. So other elements will move up to occupy that space and position accordingly.  There's a great read @ http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ that describes the collapsing of block level elements, and why it happens when they aren't also floated, or cleared.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't cleared the floats so the divs are collapsing

You can fix it with

```
.footer {
        background-color: yellow;
        clear:both;
    }
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/G9R59/)

Comment: I still don't understand, clear is about positionning not about color.

Comment: Thanks for solution, but I do want to understand the rationale behind that side effect of float which deals about positionning and should not deal with color.

Comment: When the elements collapse it's a though there were no barriers to the header color background so it carries on downward until it hits a non-floated element. Clearing floats is important.[**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/) [**MDN on Clear**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

Answer (score 1):

Putting display: inline-block and setting widths to your header and footer seem to remedy the issue!

http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/jm78Z/4/

```
div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.header{
    width: 100%;
}
.footer{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, but I do want to understand the rationale behind that side effect of float which deals about positionning and should not deal with color.

Answer (score 0):

because u have the same class name for the different div's! And Also the same id's i guess!

```
<div class='header'>
header
```

try doing dis for your next div tag

```
<div class='header1' >
header
```

in order for the css to work in different manner for different div tags u must have different identites of each div tag!

I think this link will help you
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp